# Git Lens Search by authors and search string

Tags: git, vscode-extensions, gitlens

I am trying to search text in files committed by multiple users using UI in vscode. I tried using GitLens feature search commits but cannot search by multiple users. I can do the same in command line but I would like to do that via UI.
e.g. to view commits by two users (ahmed and rana) having search term of 'abcd' I can find that by using below command.

```
git log --author=ahmed --author=rana -S abcd -i -p
```

Can the same be done using UI?